# How can I create a listview.builder in column?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem, this problem is that I want to run listview.builder in column. But when I set the scroll feature to column, the application does not work even though it does not give an error. I have codes below.

```
     return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        
        children: [
          
          Flexible(
            
            child: buildFutureBuilder(),
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


    FutureBuilder<MarkaResponse> buildFutureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<MarkaResponse>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            break;
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text("Hata"));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  
                  itemCount: 7,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    this.response = snapshot.data.liste;
                    Marka item = response[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(item.name),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.motorcycle),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Modeller(
                                      numMarka: item.id,
                                    )));
                      },
                    );
                  });
            }
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SingleChildScrollView` forces infinite height, so you can have, `Spacers`, `Expanded`,`Flexible` etc. If you give  a fixed height for your `ListView` it will work

Comment: @EDMGL glad to be of help

Answer (score 0):

Make a parent `container` for `ListView.builder`, and set a height of that `container`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
     return SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      child: Column(
        
        children: [
          Container(height: 50),
          Expanded(
            child: buildFutureBuilder(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }


    FutureBuilder<MarkaResponse> buildFutureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<MarkaResponse>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            break;
          default:
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text("Hata"));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 7,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    this.response = snapshot.data.liste;
                    Marka item = response[index];
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(item.name),
                      leading: Icon(Icons.motorcycle),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Modeller(
                                      numMarka: item.id,
                                    )));
                      },
                    );
                  });
            }
        }
      },
    );
  }
```